# R within() function: unexpected error when last value(s) are NA

Tags: r

I have encountered some unexpected behaviour when using the within() function in R.  I (eventually!) tracked the cause to a situation where the last element(s) of particular columns in question in a data frame contain NA.

I have simplified the code  to create a reproducible example.  Obviously the real world application in which I encountered this is substantially more complex (data frame >500k rows 400 columns, >100 lines inside within(), etc.), and rather inconvenient to avoid using within().

This works as expected:

```
fooTest <- data.frame(Group = c("Shell", NA,  "Cup", NA,  NA),
                      CupComposition = c("Metal", NA, "Polyethylene", NA, "Test"),
                      LinerComposition = c("Polyethylene", NA, NA, NA, "Test"))
fooTest$Bearing <- NA
fooTest$Bearing[which(fooTest$Group=="Cup")] <-
  as.character(fooTest$CupComposition[which(fooTest$Group=="Cup")])
fooTest$Bearing[which(fooTest$Group=="Shell")] <-
  as.character(fooTest$LinerComposition[which(fooTest$Group=="Shell")])
fooTest$Bearing
```

Whereas this (which should be equivalent) throws an error:

```
fooTest <- data.frame(Group = c("Shell", NA,  "Cup", NA,  NA),
                      CupComposition = c("Metal", NA, "Polyethylene", NA, "Test"),
                      LinerComposition = c("Polyethylene", NA, NA, NA, "Test"))
fooTest <- within(fooTest, {
  Bearing <- NA
  Bearing[which(Group=="Cup")] <-
    as.character(CupComposition[which(Group=="Cup")])
  Bearing[which(Group=="Shell")] <-
    as.character(LinerComposition[which(Group=="Shell")])
})
```

The error message is
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, nl, value = list(Bearing = c("Polyethylene",  : 
  replacement element 1 has 3 rows, need 5

The last two rows, in which Group is NA, are evidently not being included. NA rows in the middle of the data are OK.

A couple of questions:

1. The behaviour of within() is a bit unexpected;  is this a bug?  I am not very experienced, so am slightly reticent about filing bugs where it is likely to be my understanding that is deficient!
2. In this particular case, I expect there is a neater way to populate the "Bearing" column than the method I have employed.  Suggestions welcome!

Comment: Try `within(fooTest, {Bearing <- NA; Bearing[Group=='Cup' & !is.na(Group)] <- as.character(CupComposition)[Group=='Cup' & !is.na(Group)]; Bearing[Group=='Shell' & !is.na(Group)] <- as.character(LinerComposition)[Group=='Shell' & !is.na(Group)]})`

Comment: Thanks very much for your very quick answer.  That works.  If you put it as an answer I will accept it.  I guess the moral is to avoid using which() inside within() when there are NA values (the reason for using which() in the first place!)

Comment: I posted that as an answer along with a potential solution for your big dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to use "%in%" in this case; it handles NAs nicer:

```
fooTest <- data.frame(Group = c("Shell", NA,  "Cup", NA,  NA),
                      CupComposition = c("Metal", NA, "Polyethylene", NA, "Test"),
                      LinerComposition = c("Polyethylene", NA, NA, NA, "Test"))
fooTest <- within(fooTest, {
  Bearing <- NA
  Bearing[Group %in% "Cup"] <-
    as.character(CupComposition[Group %in% "Cup"])
  Bearing[Group %in% "Shell"] <-
    as.character(LinerComposition[Group %in% "Shell"])
})
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  That is beautifully concise, and extendable to multiple values to match (though not needed in this case).  The best choice of function often seems to rest on which handles NAs better!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the error message using `within`, you can try:

```
 within(fooTest, {Bearing <- NA
      Bearing[Group=='Cup' & !is.na(Group)] <- 
           as.character(CupComposition)[Group=='Cup' & !is.na(Group)]
     Bearing[Group=='Shell' & !is.na(Group)] <- 
           as.character(LinerComposition)[Group=='Shell' & !is.na(Group)]
  })
```

It is not clear whether the `Group` column and all other columns are following some order.  From the column names, I couldn't find a common pattern that helps in matching the elements in `Group`.  Based on the example provided, you could also do (for the bigger dataset)

```
 fooTest1 <- fooTest
 fooTest1[] <- lapply(fooTest1, as.character)#convert the columns to character class
 Un1 <- sort(unique(na.omit(fooTest1$Group)))


 m1 <-  do.call(cbind,Map(function(v, x,y)
              ifelse(v==y & !is.na(v), x, NA) , list(fooTest1[,1]),
                                       fooTest1[,-1], Un1))

 indx1 <- which(!is.na(m1), arr.ind=TRUE)[,1]
 fooTest1$Bearing <- NA
 fooTest1$Bearing[indx1] <- m1[!is.na(m1)]
 fooTest1
 #   Group CupComposition LinerComposition      Bearing
 #1 Shell          Metal     Polyethylene Polyethylene
 #2  <NA>           <NA>             <NA>         <NA>
 #3   Cup   Polyethylene             <NA> Polyethylene
 #4  <NA>           <NA>             <NA>         <NA>
 #5  <NA>           Test             Test         <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  In this case I think I will go with the simpler solution, for ease of readability, and since there are only 10 lines involving which() inside within().  However, I'm sure someone will find the more complex answer useful.